# How to use raw Postgres SQL query result in Ruby on Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My application manages several translations of a field as nested fields in a form.
Initially, I used

`f.fields_for fields, translations do |locution|` to initialise the nested fields (which works fine).

Now I need to execute a more complex query to get the list of translations, and also allow the user to create new translations for each available language. So I modified the code as:

```
  <% raw_SQL = "select #{document_id} as document_id, '#{document_type}' as document_type, '#{field_name}' as field_name, property as language,
  case when property = language then existing_translations.id else null end as id,
  case when property = language then existing_translations.translation else null end as translation
  from
  (select * from dqm_app.translations where document_id = #{document_id} and field_name = '#{field_name}' and document_type = '#{document_type}') as existing_translations
  right outer join (select property
  from dqm_app.parameters inner join dqm_app.parameters_lists on parameters.parameters_list_id = parameters_lists.id
  where parameters_lists.CODE = 'LIST_OF_LANGUAGES') as langues on property = language" %>
  <% f.fields_for fields, ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(raw_SQL).to_a do |locution| %>
```

Translation exists for French only, other translations can be added by user thanks to the nested fields to be created:
[image: Query result]

The query returns the expected result, but in the form of array of hashes instead of an ActiveRecord collection. How can I make this result usable for the fields_for method?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a model that has these attributes and cast the results yourself.

```
records = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(raw_sql).to_a
records.map { |attrs| YourModel.new(attrs) }
```

This would work because Rails allows you to initialize a model through a hash like

`YourModel.new({ id: 1 })`

Map will go over each element in the array and initialize them individually.